# WiFi network keep disconnecting

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I'm connected through wifi router and I'm experiencing some issues with the network.

Sometimes, the wifi connection is disabled and I couldn't connect to the network again. When I disable and re-enable the wireless network, the connection to the internet gets established, however after a while (sometimes few seconds, sometimes few hours) the connection gets lost and either the wifi network is not on the list or the it is but it is not able to connect ("Windows was not able to connect to this netowork").

I have this problem with this particular wifi network with more than one device and all those devices work properly on other wifi networks. There has to be something wrong with the wifi setting, however I'm completely unable to get any information.

Is there any possible way how to get more information about the problem? It's pretty stupid that it doesn't have any error message. I'd like to know, what is wrong with the wifi network.

Comment: This could be either due to the network interface card driver or the firmware issue with the wifi router. Take a minute to analyze the issue by referring the following link: http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/wireless-tips-does-your-wireless-router-keep-disconnecting-or-dropping-the-connection/

Comment: There are quite a few possibilities here. Can you provide the make and model of the router? How about the security settings for the network?